# Stream read file, and create dynamic byte

Tags: c#, file

I hit this error

The process cannot access because it is being used by another process.

The error show at `var br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open));`

I trying to do this because i want the byte to be dynamic.

```
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {

                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(dir);


                using (Stream source = System.IO.File.OpenRead(dir))
                {
                    byte[] buffer;
                    var br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open));
                    buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);

                }
}
```

Comment: try this  `File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);`

Comment: You are trying to open two streams on the same file twice. Don't. You *arleady* have a stream, there's no reason to call `new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)`

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
using (var source = new FileStream(dir, FileMode.Open))
{
     byte[] buffer;
     var br = new BinaryReader(source);
     buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
}
```

Alternative you can do this:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(dir);
```

Comment: do u mean this  byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dir); ??

Answer (score 1):

Here you open the file at first time:

```
System.IO.File.OpenRead(dir)
```

Here you are trying to open the same file second time:

```
new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
```

Of course that file is already occupied.

Rewrite the code as follows:

```
using (var source = File.OpenRead(dir))
using (var br = new BinaryReader(source))
{
    byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)br.BaseStream.Length);
}
```